# Closest pair - too many points?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Let's examine this picture a bit.
[image]

Basically we follow the well-known steps: we sort the points, we separate the array of points in half and we recursively compute the smallest distance from the right side and from the left side.
And we consider δ as being the minimum of the two computed distances.
Let's consider a point **p**, from the left side. Now we have these assumptions:
"All points from the right side, within δ distance of **p** reside in a δ x 2δ rectangle, *R*. If each pair is at least δ apart, then there are at most 6 points inside *R*".

These assumptions are a bit ambiguous.
**1**. Where exactly should we place the rectangle? Should A be the projection of **p** on the border?

**2**. The 6 points "inside" *R* are actually the vertices and 2 of the midpoints of the rectangle?

**3**. Why are the 3 points inside the red circle candidates? The distance from A to the ones that are vertices is δ√2 > δ. And if we consider the distance between **p** and A being **x**, then the distance between **p** and the other point (the midpoint) would be **x** + δ > δ.

Source: https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The rectangle shall be placed in region P2, and yes, A shall be a projection of p on the border. The left side of the rectangle shall coincide with the median line.
2. The 6 points are the maximum number of points that can be found in the region R because the minimum distance between any two pairs of points is delta. If there are 6 points then yes the location of those points shall be as you described.
3. There can be a case where p coincides with A. Hence we know that except the two right-most vertex points, all the other 4 points can be valid candidates. Now the points on the vertex cannot by themselves be candidates but they act as the boundaries for points that we should consider as candidates.

Comment: I think that I'm starting to get it thanks to your response especially to "2". So basically if we have 6 points, this would be the unique arrangement for those points. If we have lesser points, the disposition of points within the rectangle will be more permissive.
So all it is left to do is to project the points from the right on the border, take the 6 ones who are the closest to the proj. of the original point and compute the distances? And repeat that for each point from the left side in the δ strip.

Comment: @SilentControl Yes, you have understood correctly. If there are less than six points, then they can be anywhere inside the rectangle (provided they are atleast delta apart pairwise).